# Error after migrating from 1.9.3.1 to 2.1.5

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-2.1, database

after doing a data migration from 1.9.3.1 to 2.1.5,

I get this error after it was complete,

anyone have a clue??

```
a:4:{i:0;s:15:"No such entity.";i:1;s:3465:"#0 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver/Website.php(61): Magento\Store\Model\GroupRepository->get('1')

#1 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(136): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver\Website->getDefaultStoreId(NULL)
#2 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(122): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->readStoresData()
#3 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreResolver.php(85): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getStoresData()
#4 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/StoreManager.php(154): Magento\Store\Model\StoreResolver->getCurrentStoreId()
#5 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Store/Model/StoreManagerInterface/Proxy.php(119): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager->getStore(NULL)
#6 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Resolver/Store.php(29): Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface\Proxy->getStore(NULL)
#7 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/ScopeCodeResolver.php(49): Magento\Store\Model\Resolver\Store->getScope(NULL)
#8 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Config.php(79): Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeCodeResolver->resolve('stores', NULL)
#9 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/View/DesignExceptions.php(63): Magento\Framework\App\Config->getValue('design/theme/ua...', 'stores')
#10 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/CacheIdentifierPlugin.php(43): Magento\Framework\View\DesignExceptions->getThemeByRequest(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#11 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(152): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\CacheIdentifierPlugin->afterGetValue(Object(Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Identifier\Interceptor), 'cc5db57b511d9a1...')
#12 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/PageCache/Identifier/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Identifier\Interceptor->___callPlugins('getValue', Array, Array)
#13 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/PageCache/Kernel.php(60): Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Identifier\Interceptor->getValue()
#14 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/module-page-cache/Model/App/FrontController/BuiltinPlugin.php(71): Magento\Framework\App\PageCache\Kernel->load()
#15 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(142): Magento\PageCache\Model\App\FrontController\BuiltinPlugin->aroundDispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor), Object(Closure), Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#16 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/var/generation/Magento/Framework/App/FrontController/Interceptor.php(26): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
#17 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Framework\App\FrontController\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
#18 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(258): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#19 /opt/bitnami/apps/magento/htdocs/index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http))
#20 {main}";s:3:"url";s:1:"/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";}
```

Answer (score 0):

first install new magento setup without sample data

You can try this module

create folder structure like app/code/Ubertheme/Ubdatamigration

and install this module

https://github.com/ubertheme/module-ubdatamigration

It is work for me

Comment: What version of magento have you used?

Comment: 1.9.2.4  to  2.1.5

Comment: after run this link     baseurl/pub/ub-tool/index.php